# Android 10 system taking up too much hard drive space

Tags: internal-storage

I have a Nokia 5.3 running Android 10. Of the 64GB hard drive space, the system file is currently taking up 52GB.

Couple of days back, it was taking up 48GB and my phone was complaining of running out of hard drive space, so I removed some old apps and files to free up some room, and now it looks like the system file has just expanded to take up the available free space, and again it's complaining about running out of hard drive space.

How do I go about reclaiming some of the space taken by the system folder(s), as I can't believe that it's needed to write 4GB worth of data in a few days, nor that the OS really needs 52GB of hard drive space, when my old phone only had a 32GB hard drive for the same OS.

(apologies, I'm not entirely sure what tags to use for this)

Comment: There is no "system file" on Android. Android has a system partition which is of fixed size unless you completely repartition your device (and erase all user data). If you have a large file on your device you should use a file explorer to look at it and note the full path. Then edit your question and add this path.

Comment: Following Robert's comment, you can try [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) to list all big files on the storage (disclaimer: not affiliated, just a long-time user). However, you need root access to also list the internal storage.